# Overflowing the stack memory with my quadtree class and don't know why

Tags: c++, recursion, stack-overflow

I have been working on a quadtree class for possible collision detections, but the more items I add the faster I overflow the stack.

I also noticed the memory usage increases linearly as the program runs so I assume I am not deleting something properly and it is just stacking on each other?

I know most stack overflow errors are caused by recursion but it shouldn't be happening with just 100 objects.

```
#include "Quadtree.h"

Quadtree::Quadtree(Rectangle* bounds)
{
    this->bIsSplit = false;
    this->bounds = bounds;
    this->maxObjects = 5;
}

void Quadtree::Split(std::vector<std::pair<SpaceObject*, SpaceObject*>> &collidingObjects)
{
    float x = bounds->x;
    float y = bounds->y;
    float subWidth = bounds->width / 2;
    float subHeight = bounds->height / 2;

    // Top Left
    nodes.push_back(new Quadtree(new Rectangle(x, y, subWidth, subHeight)));
    // Top Right
    nodes.push_back(new Quadtree(new Rectangle(x + subWidth, y, subWidth, subHeight)));
    // Bottom Left
    nodes.push_back(new Quadtree(new Rectangle(x, y + subHeight, subWidth, subHeight)));
    // Bottom Right
    nodes.push_back(new Quadtree(new Rectangle(x + subWidth, y + subHeight, subWidth, subHeight)));

    // takes all the objects in the parent node and splits them into there corresponding subdivided quadtree
    for (auto o : this->objects)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
        {
            if (nodes[i]->bounds->Contains(o->x, o->y, o->size))
            {
                nodes[i]->Insert(o, collidingObjects);
            }
        }
    }

    this->objects.clear();
    this->bIsSplit = true;
}

void Quadtree::Insert(SpaceObject* spaceObject, std::vector<std::pair<SpaceObject*, SpaceObject*>> &collidingObjects)
{
// if the object does not fit inside this quadtree, this isn't the right quadtree
if (!bounds->Contains(spaceObject->x, spaceObject->y, spaceObject->size))
{
    return;
}

if (!bIsSplit && this->objects.size() < maxObjects) // add the object to the quadtree if the max has not been hit
{
    objects.push_back(spaceObject);

    for (auto o : this->objects)
    {
        // if the objects are not the same and overlapping (pythag)
        if (spaceObject != o &&
            ((spaceObject->x - o->x) * (spaceObject->x - o->x)) + ((spaceObject->y - o->y) * (spaceObject->y - o->y)) <= (spaceObject->size + o->size) * (spaceObject->size + o->size))
        {
            // Add colliding pair to the collidingObjects vector
            collidingObjects.push_back(std::make_pair(spaceObject, o));
        }
    }

}
else
{
    if (!this->bIsSplit) // splits the quadtree if this quadtree has not been split yet
    {
        this->Split(collidingObjects);
    }

    // adds the passed in object to one of the subnodes
    for (auto n : nodes)
    {
        n->Insert(spaceObject, collidingObjects);
    }
}
}

void Quadtree::Delete(SpaceObject* spaceObject)
{
    if (!bounds->Contains(spaceObject->x, spaceObject->y, spaceObject->size))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!bIsSplit)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
        {
            if (objects[i] == spaceObject)
            {
                this->objects.erase(objects.begin() + i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (auto n : nodes)
        {
            n->Delete(spaceObject);
       }
    }
}

void Quadtree::Clear()
{
    if (bIsSplit)
    {
        for (auto n : nodes)
        {
            n->Clear();
        }
        this->bIsSplit = false;
    }
    nodes.clear();
    objects.clear();
}
```

Comment: Even just two objects in your scene can lead to infinite recursion (and infinite loops if you write your code non-recursively) on quadtree traversal if they're perfectly coincident. You generally need some maximum depth limit to a spatial index of this sort or a minimum cell size which effectively limits the maximum depth. Without meaning to be rude, I think at your level you'd fare much better with a spatial hash than quadtree. There's less fiddling involved after you settle on cell size and I genuinely think you'll get better results from it until you start getting the hang of things.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't tell what `nodes` is or how `Quadtree` is defined because you are not showing the complete code.  But it's suspicious that you are using `new`.  Is `nodes` a collection of pointers?  If so, you are probably dropping them on the floor since they are never deleted.

---

Don't write `this->` all over the place.  Members are in the scope of the member functions.  Your `Quadtree` constructor should be using inline initializers for the constant members and an initializer list for the `bounds`.  And, using a bare pointer here is a red flag.  What is the ownership of this `bounds`?  Why does it need to be a pointer rather than simply a value of type Rectangle?

I wonder if you are used to a different language, one that uses `new` for all construction, and has reference semantics and objects are really pointers.  C++ is different.

I'd suggest writing it without using any pointers.  For sure, the `Rectangle` should be a value.  A vector of `Quadtree` *can* be efficient when inserting and deleting etc. if the elements can be efficiently *moved*.  So, `Quadtree` should have a move constructor.  That is probably an advanced concept if you don't know all about constructors and special members yet.

What you should definitely follow, even as (especially as) a beginner, is [⧺C.149](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c149-use-unique_ptr-or-shared_ptr-to-avoid-forgetting-to-delete-objects-created-using-new) — no naked `new` or `delete`.  So, if you need to make a vector of *pointers* to `Quadtree`, make it a vector of `shared_ptr`.  Remember, you don't have garbage collection in C++ so anything that's using a pointer has to explicitly deal with responsibility of lifetime management.  A `shared_ptr` will behave more like you're used to, and they are safe for use in containers like `vector`.

Comment: I am used to using C# usually but nodes is a vector of quadtree* and bounds is a Rectangle struct inside the quadtree class. Sorry about that.

Comment: OK, yea, get rid of all the pointers and work with value semantics.  Follow [⧺C.149](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c149-use-unique_ptr-or-shared_ptr-to-avoid-forgetting-to-delete-objects-created-using-new) — no naked `new` or `delete`.  Values should be good for the Rectangle.  If you need the vector to be of pointers for efficiency, use `shared_ptr`.  Better yet, make it not inefficient by providing for _move_ semantics.

Comment: So the 'nodes' vector was the memory leak, switching that fixed my memory issue. But I am still getting stack overflows at almost random it seems. Do you see any condition that the recursive loop might not exit?

Comment: @SamHirsch I suggest (after cleaning up the code and formatting) adding some print statements so you can see what the recursion is doing.